# Real-world adoption of HTML5 <ins/> tag

Tags: html, adblock

*Whilst examining AdBlock Plus settings and comparing with the DOM of a page full of AdChoices blocks, I spotted an unfamiliar tag...*

Google Ad syndication uses markup with the signature structure `<ins><ins><iframe/></ins></ins>`

From the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/spec.html):

> The [ins](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/spec.html#ins) element represents a range of text that has been inserted (added) to a document.

and

> The [del](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/spec.html#del) element represents a range of text that has been deleted from a document.

These tags both have optional `cite` and `datetime` attributes.

**Would blocking instances of `<ins/>` without a `datetime` attribute increase or reduce the utility of my web browser?**

Answer (score 1):

`ins` and `del` have been around at least since [`HTML 4.01`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.4) with an optional `datetime` attribute. AFAIK all browsers support it with or without optional attributes. Though it is not used often or may be used mostly by programmer types, it is in active use, **often without a `datetime` attribute**.

**Removing or blocking `ins` would deprive you of useful information on pages where it is used appropriately.**

Comment: Do you have examples of pages where it is used appropriately, that you have accessed in day-to-day browsing?

Comment: Well, being a web developer I used to follow a lot of blogs discussing matters of semantics, and those websites attempted to use `ins` and `del` on occasion. I can't find a single use by searching google though. But I remembered this excellent rant: [Why html5 elements INS and DEL suck](http://www.glazman.org/weblog/dotclear/index.php?post/2011/06/25/Why-html5-elements-INS-and-DEL-suck) by [Daniel Glazman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Glazman)